# tcl thread::send -async not works

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I want to send message to thread in synchronous mode and get result using trace variable metohd. The problem is that I dont get any response from thread. When I send message in normal mode (thread:: send thread_id {command} var) then I also get the result which is saved in var. Could anyone point out where I make mistake ? Below I pass my code :

```
trace add variable res write {apply {{v1 v2 op} {
  upvar 1 $v1 v
  puts "updated variable to $v"}}}

set th [thread::create {

  puts "new thread id : [thread::id]"
  proc fun {n} {
     return [expr {$n*2}]
  }
  thread::wait
}]
# thread::send $th [list fun $t] res
thread::send -async $th [list fun 43] res
```

Comment: The [thread manual page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/ThreadCmd/thread.htm) states: "If the -async flag is specified, the command does not wait for the result and it returns empty string ."  What were you expecting to happen?  Variables are not shared across threads and cannot be traced across threads.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I thought that after some time the res value will change and I will be able to register this event asynchronously. There is any other way to register the end of th thread in main thread without using vwait ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you waiting for events in the source/main thread? If you aren't, you'll never process the asynchronous response message that causes the `res` variable to be set.